# Janus GridEX SelfReferencing Setting

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, janus, gridex

I want to Load my tree as Hirarchical in Janus GridEX , but when I set the setting it is not working , my table columns are:

```
TopicID nvarchar(50)  ; --which is parent
ParentID nvarchar(50) ;--which is child
Description nvarchar(50);
```

and the setting window is like as following 
[image: this is how I set the settings]

Also I checked with GridEX tutorial every thing is ok but not working for me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did following settings and it works like a charm .
[image]